# How should I store variables between method calls in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

I'm fairly new to RoR I have a controller and within that controller I need to store an instance variable I create in the new method and reference it again in the create method.

Now because HTTP is stateless the only reasonable way I have found to do this is store the id of the model that the instance variable contains in `session[]` and then recall this value from `session[]` again in the create method. I'm just concerned about security using this way of storing the variable's id, I need to make sure that a user can't change the value of what I've stored in `session[]`

Is there a better way for me to do this? Is it safe? Or should I try something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't recalculate that model id on every request, using a session is ok.
Here's more info on [session security in Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sessions).

Comment: They can't really touch the session, so you should be ok ;)

Answer (score 0):

if you can load the model in the `new` method, load it from `create` using the same way you load it in `new`

Comment: I can't, I'm taking a parameter from the URL and loading a model based on that parameter then storing the id of the model in the variable. I can't access the same parameter from the URL in the create method because it's a different URL. :)